# How to redirect tomcat Server from webapp1 to webapp2 using rewrite.config

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, mod-rewrite, tomcat8

rewrite.config :

**RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} ^/dic/**
**RewriteRule ^/(.*) /webapp2/doc**

for Example : the current code

localhost:8085/webapp1/dic ==> localhost:8085/webapp1/webapp2/doc

But the result should be

localhost:8085/webapp1/dic ==> localhost:8085/webapp2/doc

Comment: The [`RewriteValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html) can be added to a `Context`, `Host` or `Engine`. Where did you add it? Absolute URI paths are interpreted as relative to the context if you added it to a `Context`.

Comment: the  RewriteValve is added in context.xml , I wanna change the context path of my webapp1  just using rewrite.config file